# directions + road APIs for educational purpose

Tags: google-maps-api-3

my team members and I are university students doing our industrial project which is going to predict the arrival times for ambulance cars to patients and then to hospitals based on various factors.
Our system will be extensively querying from Google maps apis especially road and direction apis. So is there any chance to get a premium access to these apis since it will be only used for educational purpose?
Thanks:)

Comment: You really should contact Google directly about that...

Answer (score 0):

Google has Google Maps APIs Grants (Premium plan for free) available for nonprofit organizations in the United States.

If your organization meets these requirements you can reach out to Google and apply to Grant as described in the following document:

https://support.google.com/nonprofits/answer/3367237?hl=en

Hope this helps!